# Rails 5: Insert/Update only if there's no filled specific field for that id

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Followups` table with the fields: `patient_id`, `death_date` (and other fields..).

There could be multiple records for the same `patient_id` but there must be only one `death_date` for that `patient_id`.
A unique index won't work as the user could insert two different death_date.

Which is the best way to achieve this in Rails 5?

If possible, please make an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a callback on the `Followup` model:
Assuming a `Patient` `has_many :followups`

```
class Followup
  belongs_to :patient
  validate :check_for_existing_death_date

  private

  def check_for_existing_death_date
    # This will grab the first one if any with a death date exist
    # This also assumes that the patient_id and patient exist
    followup = patient.followups.where("death_date IS NOT NULL").take

    # if you want to raise an error...
    if followup
      errors.add(:death_date, 'There is already a death date for this patient')
      return false
    end

    # If not, do something with the data
    # if followup
    #   self.death_date = nil # or followup.death_date if you want it saved on followups as well
    # end
  end
end
```

I would think that the best way to do this would be to store the `death_date` on the `Patient` record, since death only happens once per patient.

Comment: You are right, and I had stored the date in Patient but then I  put it in Followup upon committent's request. (I would have probably avoid this if I was more skilled in Rails..).
However, your solution works for new insert but delete the date in update even if there is only one death_date stored in db.
Also, how can I stop update/insert and show an error?

Comment: Then you can change it to a validation. Updated answer.

Comment: it still raises an error on update of the unique date in db. Thank you for your patient..

Comment: Ah, well that's probably a separate validation issue on the model. You might have to add `allow_nil: true` to that validation, but I can't say more without seeing the whole model. Glad it (kind of) works. At least you're on the right track